# rspec error 'undefined method' valid? in my user_spec model - ruby on rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I get following error when running rspec:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

> Failures:
>
> 1) User when name is too long 
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not be_vaild }
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `vaild?' for #<User:0x007f8eebf0d6c0>
>        # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:39:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.22196 seconds 6 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:39 # User when name is too long

my user.rb file

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email,

 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 validates :email, presence: true

end
```

my user_spec.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

    before do
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
    end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_vaild }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a typo, misspelled valid

> valid

not

> vaild

Comment: You should be sure to mark this answer as accepted, to indicate the question has been satisfactorily answered.